# Fourier transform of certain complex functions including conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

For $y,a,t,s\in\mathbb{R},y\neq 0,t,s>1$, how can we compute the following integral?
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x+iy)^{-s}(x-iy)^{-t}e^{2\pi i ax}dx$$

Comment: What is the context in which this integral arises? Maybe this helps.

Comment: This question occurs when I was learning Stein's Complex analysis Chapter 4 Fourier transform. I want to try to calculate some integral, whose degree is not an integer. ( I feel uncomfortable that the way using residues can only deal with integral degree.

Comment: The problem with the residue formula for exponents not in Z is that these functions are not even meromorphic: I don't know how much you already know about complex roots, but even a function like $f(z) = \sqrt{z}$ makes problems, since it is not holomorphic around $0$. In fact, this is a multivalued function: Write $z = r e^{i\phi}$: $$f(z) = \sqrt{r} e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}.$$ Even though $r e^{i\phi} = z=r e^{i(\phi+2\pi)}$, we get $$f(z)=\sqrt{r} e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}} = f(r e^{i\phi}) = f(re^{i(\phi+2\pi)}) = \sqrt{r} e^{i(\frac{\phi}{2}+\pi)} = -f(z),$$ which contradicts e.g. $f(1)\neq 0$

Comment: This means that the expression $f(z) = \sqrt{z}$ is not well-defined, unless we choose a domain so that the above situation can not occur: On $D^+ = \{ r e^{i\phi}\in\mathbb{C} : r\in(0,\infty), \phi\in (0,\pi)\}$, $f|_{D^+} =: +\sqrt{z}$ is indeed a holomorphic function, and the same is true for the lower half plane (i.e. $\phi\in(\pi,2\pi)$).

Comment: In particular, you cannot talk about Laurent series or residue for this function at $z=0$, since any path enclosing $0$ necessarily must cross from the upper to the lower halfplane